# How do you remove reported non existing tables from mysql?

Tags: mysql

I was trying to export a `mysqldump --all-databases` and noted errors. A subsequent

`mysqlcheck --all-databases`

revealed several non existent tables like the following

`Error    : Table 'stats.scoring_campaign_countries_99save' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed`

Of course I can't drop a table if it does't exist so how to fix this?

The tables are using MyISAM.

Comment: What engine are you using?

Answer (score 2):

If using MyISAM, you should be able to get rid of the tables by deleting the .frm files from the data folder while the database is down.

Remember to backup everything you can before doing anything like that!

Comment: Only one table has a .frm file, the others reported are MIA